# permutations of a certain length

Tags: java, permutation

I am trying to find the permutations of a string of a certain length.

ex:

```
java --> permutations of length 2

ja,jv,ja | aj,av,aa | vj, va, va | aj, aa, av
```

What I am having trouble with right now is starting the iteration through different parts of the string.

ex:

create strings in this order iterating at different parts of the string

j --> a,v,a

a --> j,v,a

v --> j,a,a

This is the small bit of code I have so far

```
// iterate through each character in string
for (int i = 0; i < strlen; i++) {
  String strBuffer = ""; 
  char mainChar str.charAt(i);
  for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {  // stop at set length
  /*
   * iterate through different parts at different points
   * 
   */
  }
```

Comment: _Permutations of length k_ has already been solved many times. The entire program is even written for you in Java. 5 seconds on Google led me to this wonderful algorithm. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-given-length/